# Can i call the root borderpane in the controller class without reloading the fxml file

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller

I' m trying to build a small javafx application that communicates with a database. The app should have a borderpane where in the top i set a menubar and in the center an anchorpane with some fields and buttons. When the user pushes a menu item then a new anchorpane with a button should open in the center of the root borderpane preserving the menubar on the top. Finally, I managed to build this UI by reloading the Rootlayout fxml in the controller's eventhandler function. Is there a more efficient way to refer/call to Rootlayout without reloading it in the controller's event handler function?

This the structure of my project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNbYr.png)

Main Class

```
package sample;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;
    public BorderPane rootLayout;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        this.primaryStage=primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Expenses JavaFX App");
        initRootLayout();
        showOwnersOperationsView();


    }
    //Initializes the root layout.
    public void initRootLayout() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene); //Set the scene in primary stage.
            primaryStage.show(); //Display the primary stage
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Shows the owners operations view inside the root layout.
    public void showOwnersOperationsView() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/OwnerOperations.fxml"));
            AnchorPane ownerOperationsView = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            // Set Owner Operations view into the center of root layout.
            rootLayout.setCenter(ownerOperationsView);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package sample.controller;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import sample.Main;


import java.io.IOException;

public class RootLayoutController implements Initializable{
    //Exit the program
    public void handleExit(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
    public BorderPane rootLayout;
    @FXML
    BorderPane myPane;
    @FXML
    private void changeScene (ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException  {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            FXMLLoader loader1 = new FXMLLoader();
            AnchorPane TotalExpensesView = (AnchorPane)  loader1.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sample/view/Total_expenses.fxml"));

            Stage stage = (Stage) myPane.getScene().getWindow();
            Scene scene= new Scene(rootLayout);
            stage.setTitle("Flats");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
            rootLayout.setCenter(TotalExpensesView);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problem occurred while change scene: " + e);
        }
    }
@Override
    public void initialize (URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    }
}
```

RootLayout.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane fx:id="myPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.controller.RootLayoutController">
   <top>
      <MenuBar fx:id="myMenuBar" prefWidth="800.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
                  <MenuItem fx:id="scene" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#changeScene" text="NewScene" />
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

I tried to reload the Rootlayout.fxml in the controller and it seems to work. But is this way efficient? I couldn't find any other way to refer to the Main's  rootLayout from the controller.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
```

Comment: as to your problem: don't quite understand why you re-load the fixed part of the ui (essentially the menu) instead of replacing only the center?

Comment: Actually, this is exactly my problem. I can't understand how to just replace only the center. How to refer to the center of my borderPane from the controller?

Comment: well, it _is_ inside your controller .. let it do its stuff, why do you want replace it from somewhere else?

Comment: The root layout is just `myPane`. It's really not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Yes James_D you are right. I just got confused on how to refer to the root layout. The only thing i need is "myPane.setCenter(TotalExpensesView);"  I got it. Thank u both